# Doesn`t find i18n .json | Angular

Tags: angular, localization, ngx-translate

I use for localization ngx-translate in my Angular app. On debug mode everything is working well.
On prod in my Azure WebAppService I have this.

[image]

local

[image]

I read that this could fix the problem

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "assets/i18n/", ".json");
}
```

but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share your web.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happened to me once and i was missing the **json mimeType** in my web.config.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
...
```

Comment: where can I find this file in my Angular app, I don`t see web.config

Comment: I losted create my web.config file.